# Cost of bulkUpdate

Tags: bulk-api, node.js, jsforce

I'm using jsforce to perform a `bulkUpdate` on `Records`.

I have a broker `Node` App that retrieves records from an external API. It then needs to update said records to Salesforce.

This Node app will perform this sync nightly. It may download ~20k records.
Only a percentage of these records may actually have their fields be changed (Let's just say 5k..so ~25%).

Is it worth it to spend the dev time (not to mention resources of the node app) and check through every of the 20k records, make note of updates, and then send to SF? Or is an unconditional `bulkUpdate` of those ~20k benign ?

Comment: What happens if fields have changed in salesforce before last update? Which system is master of the records?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't care if the data might be updated in Salesforce (e.g. it is intended to be one-way), and the updates won't take long (e.g. there's no heavy automation or triggers involved), then Bulk API is the way to go, and you can just update everything. However, if it would run for hours, or if you might accidentally overwrite data, I'd suggest going with normal synchronous API calls. There's no "one right answer" here, and it may even change over time.

Comment: No need for heavy automation or triggers. I'd essentially be doing the equivalent of a big csv upload with the SF Data Loader app. The way I see it is "unnecessary" overwrites would happen in any upsert of a regular DB anyways. I.e. a `INSERT INTO...ON DUPLICATE KEY VALUE` in regular SQL would still return a "rows Affected" of all Objects from the API call (regardless of if there was a change in data or not - so essentially an overrwrite). I guess I should've asked if there was any concern in the efficiency of a bulkUpdate if there are lots of benign overwrites. Subjective for sure

Comment: @user2402616 Nah, shouldn't be an issue as a general rule of thumb. That'd what I'd do for a large upload to a lightweight object.